# Qwt moc issue (moc.exe not found)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw32, qwt, moc

I've a big issue since last week, and I can't find any working solution.

When I compile **`Qwt 6.1.2`** (and try next with **`6.1.3`**) on a **`Windows 7 32bits`**  with [mingw32](/questions/tagged/mingw32) console, and after compiling sequence, i have the following message:

> `usr/bin/sh: C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\mingw49_32\bin\moc.exe : command not found`

I try to change `\` with `/` in `makefile.release`/ `makefile.debug` and it still doesn't work.

I hope someone have a solution for that.

PS: I build Qwt with an other PC with Windows 10 and work normally.

Comment: It looks like some Unix thing tries to access Windows-like path. This can't work.

Comment: Yes it what i thought, i remove all unix things in makefile.release and qwtconfig but not work :/ I  really do not know what to do to make it work. I search in my environment PATH if i don't have any cyqwin or MSYS path but nothing found :/

Comment: Is Qt installed at that location? If yes, I think the format should be `/c/Qt/...` instead of `C:\Qt\...`.

Comment: yes Qt is install at C:/ i'll try with /c/

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyvandeGlind this work perfectly. The problem is solve

Comment: No problem. Now, I don't have the environment to test it, but I think the actual problem lies in that you called your `qmake` from a windows environment and your make from a mingw32 environment.

Comment: I think too but don't know why, i do exactly the same procedure with another PC and it work without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

What helped was checking the Windows Path settings and removing all paths that would include a sh.exe binary (in my case Cygwin and Git for Windows). You could also change your Qt console path settings locally. Seems like qmake is generating Makefiles based on if 'sh' was found on the system or not.

Comment: could be comment then answer